# SecurityException in android Binder invocation to an incorrect interface

Tags: android

I am using enqueue method to implement `JobIntentService`. But I am facing few errors which are listed below,

```
2019-04-03 17:03:38.832 15796-15809/mobi.durga W/Parcel:

**** enforceInterface() expected mobi.durga.services.player.IMediaPlaybackService' but read'android.app.job.IJobService'

     2019-04-03 17:03:38.833 15796-15809/mobi.durga W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.

     java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
at android.os.Parcel.nativeEnforceInterface(Native Method)
at android.os.Parcel.enforceInterface(Parcel.java:610)
at mobi.durga.services.player.IMediaPlaybackService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaPlaybackService.java:48)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

**Code:**

```
final Intent i = new Intent(context, MediaPlaybackService.class);
    i.setAction(MediaPlaybackService.SERVICECMD);
    i.putExtra(MediaPlaybackService.CMDNAME, 
    MediaPlaybackService.CMDOPEN_AND_PLAY);
    i.putExtra(MediaPlaybackService.TRACKPOS, position);
    /*Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, MediaPlaybackService.class);
    mIntent.putExtra("maxCountValue", 1000);
    MediaPlaybackService.enqueueWork(context, mIntent);*/
    if (CoreHelper.isPieCompatible()) {
        Log.d("in cmd manager","in line 59");
    // ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, i);
        MediaPlaybackService.enqueueWork(context, i);
    }
    else {
       context.startService(i);
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us your code and the full stacktrace of the errors in order for us to help

Comment: Please edit your question with the added information. Comments are only for discussion

Comment: Just now edited my question once check it out.

Comment: You also need to show us the code you are using which causes the issue.

Comment: Just now added my code.we are using enqueue work instead of foreground service.

Comment: did you find a cause/solution?